# Doctrine messing up queries on Entities with an Extends

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

My task is (or was) simple: There is a variety but finite types of "Post", each with a vastly different set of properties while all sharing a couple core properties (like: Title, Content, Published, etc)

What I set out to do, was create a base `Post` entity with all the shared properties (as mentioned above), and have this entity as sort of a "Governor" entity, but more on that in a second.  All the different `Category` entities would extend off of this base Post entity.

I did it this way mostly to appeal to the strengths of the Symfony Form API. There are just way too many fields per different Category type to warrant not doing something a bit automated. With the Form API, I can have Symfony use Doctrine to automatically create the editable fields on a page and populate each field with the acquired value when editing (or blank if unpopulated or new), without me having to individually provide them in HTML.

When I said "Governor" I meant I also wanted the base Post to have it's own Repository, and ideally no associated table. This repository could be used to do certain tasks which is Post Type agnostic, such as a `findAll()` override that would query each of the Category repositories and merge the results into one result (for example)

Ideally I just wanted to define the unique property of each category in exactly one location, the Entity, and it would reflect across the entirety of the site. Rather than defining it in the entity, the Edit Form, the front end, table fields, etc.

**the problem**

It seems to be messing up the built in queries which I have not overridden.

consider (please note the bolded text):

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT **t1.id** AS id2, t1.title
>   AS title3, t1.slug AS slug4, t1.date_added AS date_added5,
>   t1.date_updated AS date_updated6, t1.content AS content7, t1.published
>   AS published8, t1.uid AS uid9, *[SENSITIVE FIELDS REDACTED]* FROM
>   PostCategoryTest t1 WHERE **t0.id = ?'** with params ["1"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.id' in
>   'where clause'

This is caused when I call a basic `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(PostCategoryTest::DoctrinePath)->find(1)`

**The source**

CommonBundle/Entity/Post.php

```
<?php

namespace CommonBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CommonBundle\Entity\PostRepository")
 */
abstract class Post
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $slug;

    //... and so on and so fourth
}
```

CommonBundle/Entity/PostCategoryTest.php

```
<?php

namespace CommonBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table(options={"comment":"Post subclass"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CommonBundle\Entity\PostCategoryTestRepository")
 */
class PostCategoryTest extends Post
{
    const DoctrinePath = "CommonBundle:PostCategoryTest";

    // ... all sensitive information redacted, sorry
    // setup just like a standard entity however, nothing special 
}
```

I do understand there's many more ways to accomplish this, and I may just go ahead and do that as this has provided a few more headaches than I had expected. But for sake of education, I'd like to understand why Doctrine is doing this exactly.  This problem never happened when `extends`ing `BaseUser` from FOSUserBundle

Comment: Why are you doing this `const DoctrinePath = "CommonBundle:PostCategoryTest";` ? It's unrelated to the issue

Comment: @ThomasPotaire you are correct, I simply neglected to remove it from the code, I only make it a point to remove sensitive or redundant lines (getters/setters, unrelated properties, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Doctrine's documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html), there are 3 ways to extend a class:

- [Mapped superclass](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses): the parent class is **not** an entity.
- [Single table inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance): one big table for all data (including the extra fields).
- [Class table inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance): one main table, plus an extra table for each entity with extra fields.

You either want the single table inheritance or the class table inheritance.

The mapped superclass won't work because you want the parent class `Post` to be a standalone entity. In that case the `Post` class you should not define it as `abstract`.

Unless you have a large amount of extra fields you should probably use `single table inheritance`.

Comment: I appreciate this answer a lot, thank you :) From the sounds of things it may be a Class table inheritance, as it isn't just a couple fields of difference unfortunately, were talking quite a few

Comment: Not only did this help resolve the issue I was having, but has single handedly solved all of my other problems regarding this approach. Thank you so much for pointing out these inheritance types!